# Am I allowed to advertise my project related to patent system?

Tags: support, answers, site-promotion

Would the following behavior be allowed:

I would like to post a question like "What are alternative solutions to using patents to reward inventors?" and answer it myself with an advertisement of my (noncommercial) project that provides a solution to reward inventors alternative to patents.

Would be I also allowed to mention that the project now needs donations?

Answer (score 0):

Well, all I can say is that I would consider this spam.